# What types of entry points for travelers are available at Incheon Airport and what are their respective terms of use?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, south-korea, local-customs, seoul

For example, there  usually are counters for citizens / PR and counters for foreigners. What exactly does Incheon airport have?

Per the suggestion by the community, “immigration entry point” could be used to describe the thing I would like to talk about.

Comment: Do you mean immigration or customs?

Comment: Passport control = immigration; luggage control = custom*s*. Custom = habit. Please pick the right one.

Comment: @Richard Oh I’m still not familiar using English to talk about traveling stuffs. Let me explain with a bit more words. In this case, an “entry point” is an entrance where an officier checks the traveler’s documents and the traveler may be admitted into the country when requirements are met (e.g. appropriate visa or appropriate use of visa-free traveling policies); there are usually a series of entry points at an airport. I think immigration is a process of retrieving immigrating visas and/or naturalization, which is not related to this question.

Comment: @dda Thank you for the info. I have updated the question.

Comment: Immigration is also the government body that checks entry and exit of travelers. That's the word you were looking for.

Comment: In that case, on my most recent trip to Incheon, it was Koreans and residents of Korea in one line, and foreigners in the other at the immigration checkpoint. Anecdotally, I know my friend uses the Korean line with his Korean wife when he arrives. For customs, there are two lines, goods to declare, and nothing to declare.

Comment: When you get to the airport, you go to the queue that's appropriate to your situation. What difference does knowing in advance make?

Answer (score 4):

There are three types of counters in Incheon (and most other entry points in Korea, like Gimpo airport, Jeju airport, etc):

1. Manned counters for Koreans.
2. Manned counters for foreigners (residents and visitors).
3. Electronic gates for Koreans, foreign residents and registered visitors.

For the latter, a few countries and regions have signed a reciprocal agreement with South Korea. The US, Germany, Hong Kong, and a couple of others I think. You need to register with Korean Immigration, online, pass once through a manned counter, and then register physically on departure. After which you can use the electronic gates.

Korea doesn't stamp passports anymore. At manned counters for foreigners, on entry, the Immigration officer gives you a small piece of paper recording your personal details, with date of entry, and date by which you have to leave.

Comment: Isn't there a gate for diplomats and crews?

Comment: @Blaszard Indeed.

Comment: It seems that the electronic gates are available to any foreign residents that have registered: http://www.ses.go.kr/ses/SesObjectR_en.ses

Comment: @dda No German allowed in SES - but Macao and Taiwan as of August 2018.